# Set MAX_STRINGS dynamically

Tags: c, memory-management

How do I assign MAX_STRINGS to be dynamic instead of static (20)? Right now, this will accept 5 strings with a max length of 200 characters, but the expected size should be such that when the user inputs 3 asterisks (***), the number of times he inputs beforehand will be taken as the number for MAX_STRINGS For example, if a user inputs 2 words previously, and inputs 3 asterisks on the third input prompt, 2 will be set as MAX_STRINGS.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRINGS 5
#define MAX_STRING_LEN 200

void InsertionSort(char list[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN]);

int main()
{
    int index;
    char strings[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN];

    /* Get input */
    printf("Enter %d strings.\n", MAX_STRINGS);
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_STRINGS; index++)
    {
        printf("Input string %d : ", index);
        scanf("%199s", strings[index]);     // limit the width so we don't go past the buffer
        strings[index][sizeof(strings[index]) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    InsertionSort(strings);

    printf("\nThe input set, in alphabetical order:\n");
    for (index = 0; index < MAX_STRINGS; index++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[index]);
    }
}

void InsertionSort(char list[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        int j = i;

        while (j > 0 && strcmp(list[j - 1], list[j]) > 0)
        {
            char tmp[MAX_STRING_LEN];
            strncpy(tmp, list[j - 1], sizeof(tmp) - 1);
            tmp[sizeof(tmp) - 1] = '\0';

            strncpy(list[j - 1], list[j], sizeof(list[j - 1]) - 1);
            list[j - 1][sizeof(list[j - 1]) - 1] = '\0';

            strncpy(list[j], tmp, sizeof(list[j]));
            list[j][sizeof(list[j]) - 1] = '\0';

            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for _dynamic memory allocation_.

Comment: The question "linked list" in the title and uses the [tag:linked-list] tag, but this code doesn't use a linked list. Have you read the assignment properly?

Comment: Q: MAX_STRINGS to be dynamic instead of static?  A: Use a variable, instead of `#define` ;)  Q: How do I make char strings[MAX_STRING_LEN] (string length) dynamic?  A: Try [strdup()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).  Q: How do I make the list of strings dynamic?  A: Use a list, instead of using an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested code. Please find output below it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRINGS 100     // Number of strings should be less than 100
#define MAX_STRING_LEN 200  // Limit on length of each string

// void InsertionSort(char list[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LEN]);
void InsertionSort(char *list[MAX_STRINGS], int index);

int main()
{
    int index=0;
    int i;
    char *strings[MAX_STRINGS]; // Array of pointers

    /* Get Input: New code section*/

    do {
        strings[index] = malloc(MAX_STRING_LEN * sizeof(char));
        printf("Input string %d : ", index);
        scanf("%199s", strings[index]);
        strings[index][sizeof(strings[index]) - 1] = '\0';
    } while(strcmp(strings[index++], "***")!=0);

    InsertionSort(strings, index-2);  // change. -2 because the last valid 
                      // index will be excluding *** and extra post-increment

    printf("\nThe input set, in alphabetical order:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < index-1; i++)   // change. -1 to exclude ***
    {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}

void InsertionSort(char *list[MAX_STRINGS], int index)   // change
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        int j = index;  // change

        while (j > i && strcmp(list[j - 1], list[j]) > 0)   //change
        {
            char tmp[MAX_STRING_LEN];
            strncpy(tmp, list[j - 1], sizeof(tmp) - 1);
            tmp[sizeof(tmp) - 1] = '\0';

            strncpy(list[j - 1], list[j], sizeof(list[j - 1]) - 1);
            list[j - 1][sizeof(list[j - 1]) - 1] = '\0';

            strncpy(list[j], tmp, sizeof(list[j]));
            list[j][sizeof(list[j]) - 1] = '\0';

            --j;
        }
    }
}
```

Few tests:

```
$ ./a.out 
Input string 0 : cd
Input string 1 : ab
Input string 2 : ***

The input set, in alphabetical order:
ab
cd



$ ./a.out 
Input string 0 : gh
Input string 1 : ef
Input string 2 : cd
Input string 3 : ab
Input string 4 : ***

The input set, in alphabetical order:
ab
cd
ef
gh
```

`MAX_STRINGS` is now 100. It means there can be at max 100 strings. Therefore `***` can be at most at 99th index location. `malloc` is there just to save from unnecessary memory wastage. The code is easy to understand. Please go through. Let me know if you need any more explanation, I will provide.

Comment: Your code understands that "index" is the #/entries before "***".  Cool.  But I'm not 100% sure that satisfies the requirement `when the user inputs 3 asterisks (***), the number of times he inputs beforehand will be taken as the number for MAX_STRINGS`  I think maybe the point of the exercise was to make the #/items completely dynamic.  In other words, to use a ["list"](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/) instead of an array, and to eliminate `#define MAX_STRINGS` altogether.  I'm not sure :(

Comment: @paulsm4. Hmm Maybe. I will edit my answer and I will add a linked list version of the code also. Will do it in some time.